# In three.js does not work material selection through span

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

At first, span worked for me, then I set up materialsLib and initMaterialSelectionMenus from documentation and examples, but now or the span does not work, then the model does not appear.
Help, please!

UPD
The problem was in the functions. Apparently they were looped or something like that.

Some of code
main.html:

```
<canvas id="c" width="100" height="100" allowtransparency frameborder="no" scrolling="yes"</canvas>
<div id="menu">
  <div></div>
        <span>Kar color: <select id="kar-mat"></select></span><br/><br/>
        <span>Prof color: <select id="pro-mat"></select></span>
</div>
    <style>
        #c {width: 100px; height: 100px; display: block;}
        #menu {position: absolute; left: 1em; top: 1em; padding: 1em; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); color: white; font-family: monospace;}
    </style>
    <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
```

main.js:

```
var karMatSelect = document.getElementById( 'kar-mat' );
var proMatSelect = document.getElementById( 'pro-mat' );
var objParts = {
                karkass: [],
                proff: [],
            };
```

...

```
function loadModel() {
    var LOADER = new GLTFLoader();
    LOADER.crossOrigin = true;
    LOADER.load('1.glb',
    (gltf) => {
        console.log('loading complete')
        const objbox = gltf.scene;
        SCENE.add(objbox);
        console.log(objbox);
        objParts.karkass.push(objbox.getObjectByName('karkasidver')); //all objects are [Mesh]es
        objParts.proff.push(objbox.getObjectByName( 'profl' ),);
```

...

```
function initMaterials() {
            materialsLib = {
                karkaslib: [
                    new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {
                        color: 0x154889, metalness: 1, roughness: 0.2, name: '5005'
                    } ),
                   .....
                proflib: [
                    ......
                    } ),
                ],
            };
        }
        function initMaterialSelectionMenus() {
            function addOption(name, menu) {
                var option = document.createElement( 'option' );
                option.text = name;
                option.value = name;
                menu.add(option);
            }
            materialsLib.karkaslib.forEach( function ( material ) {
                addOption(material.name, karMatSelect);
            } );
            materialsLib.proflib.forEach( function ( material ) {
                addOption(material.name, proMatSelect);
            } );

            karMatSelect.selectedIndex = 2;
            proMatSelect.selectedIndex = 5;
            karMatSelect.addEventListener( 'change', updateMaterials );
            proMatSelect.addEventListener( 'change', updateMaterials );
        }
        function updateMaterials() {
            initMaterials()
            var karkasMat = materialsLib.karkaslib[karMatSelect.selectedIndex];
            var proflMat = materialsLib.karkaslib[proMatSelect.selectedIndex];
            objParts.karkass.forEach(part => part.material = karkasMat);
            objParts.proff.forEach(part => part.material = proflMat);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I started the project, I had errors in the console. I made a few changes to fix it:

1. In `loadModel` I have add rows with `initMaterials();` and `initMaterialSelectionMenus();`

```js
    objParts.karkass.push(objbox.getObjectByName('karkasidver'));
    objParts.proff.push(objbox.getObjectByName('profl'));
    console.log(dumpObject(objbox).join('\n')); //-список объектов в сцене
    /* Add function call for initialization*/
    initMaterials();

    updateMaterials();

    /* Add function call for UI initialization*/
    initMaterialSelectionMenus();
```

2. I have add checks for undefined for `karkasMat` and `proflMat` in the function `updateMaterials`. Also I have removed call `initMaterials()`.

```js
function updateMaterials() {
    /*  Remove call for initMaterials() */
    var karkasMat = materialsLib.karkaslib[karMatSelect.selectedIndex];
    var proflMat = materialsLib.karkaslib[proMatSelect.selectedIndex];

    /*  added check for empty element */
    if (karkasMat) {
        objParts.karkass.forEach(part => part.material = karkasMat);
    }
    /*  added check for empty element */
    if (proflMat) {
        objParts.proff.forEach(part => part.material = proflMat);
    }
}
```

  3.

```js
function updateCamera() {
   CAMERA.updateProjectionMatrix();

   /* Remove next rows, because animation function already started, and will update controls and render scene*/
   // CONTROLS.update();
   // RENDERER.render(SCENE, CAMERA);
   // animate()
  }
```

#### Result

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

Alex has an error:
in `function updateMaterials()`

var proflMat = materialsLib.**karkaslib**[proMatSelect.selectedIndex];

instead of

var proflMat = materialsLib.**proflib**[proMatSelect.selectedIndex];